# Convert SQL Data in columns into an array

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

Imagine you have a simple table

```
  Key c1 c2 c3
A id1  x  y  z
B id2  q  r  s
```

what I would like is a query that gives me the result as 2 arrays
so something like

```
Select
id1,
ARRAY_MAGIC_CREATOR(c1, c2, c3)
from Table
```

With the result being

```
id1, <x,y,z>
id2, <q,r,s>
```

Almost everything I have searched for end up converting rows to arrays or other similar sounding but very different requests.

Does something like this even exist in SQL?
Please note that the data type is NOT a string so we can't use string concat.  They are all going to be treated as floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `ARRAY`:

```
Select id1, ARRAY[c1, c2, c3] as c_array
from Table
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work :o)

```
select key, [c1, c2, c3] c
from `project.dataset.table`
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below generic option which does not require you to type all columns names or even to know them in advance - more BigQuery'ish way of doing business :o)

```
select key, 
  regexp_extract_all(
    to_json_string((select as struct * except(key) from unnest([t]))),
    r'"[^":,]+":([^":,]+)(?:,|})'
  ) c
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]